# How to sort an object by date in keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
var obj = { 2017-05-28: 76.16108625212159, 2017-02-12: 70.32183347555772, 2017-05-21: 74.21070693205216, 2017-04-23: 78.49819059107358, 2017-03-05: 73.36286201022146, 2017-04-02: 79.07588060050237, 2017-01-29: 79.07021235890568, 2017-03-26: 74.79360018220122, 2017-01-22: 71.80166785183269, 2017-04-09: 72.68569443640364 };
```

I would like to sort it by date, beginning from January, but I have no idea how to do this.

What do you think, is it possible in JS ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Please, copy your object and put it into the question. *You can use JSON.stringify(object)* to print it as string  so you can copy it easily.

Comment: I've updated my post, thanks

Comment: I copied it from Firefox console]

Comment: Objects don't hold any order in Javascript, so first you need to convert it to an array. Then use [`array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: And how to convert it to an object after the sort ?

Comment: @john_js_py Converting the array back to an object loses any sorting you've just done. Keep it as an array if you want to access the sorted elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of keys is not guaranteed in an object. you can convert your data structure into a sorted array as shown below and iterate over the array in order for your needs:

```js
var obj = {
  "2017-05-28": 76.16108625212159,
  "2017-02-12": 70.32183347555772,
  "2017-05-21": 74.21070693205216,
  "2017-04-23": 78.49819059107358,
  "2017-03-05": 73.36286201022146,
  "2017-04-02": 79.07588060050237,
  "2017-01-29": 79.07021235890568,
  "2017-03-26": 74.79360018220122,
  "2017-01-22": 71.80166785183269,
  "2017-04-09": 72.68569443640364
};

var sortedArray = Object.keys(obj).sort().map(function(key) {
  return {
    date: key,
    value: obj[key]
  }
});

console.log(sortedArray);
/**Outputs:
[
  {
    "date": "2017-01-22",
    "value": 71.80166785183269
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-01-29",
    "value": 79.07021235890568
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-02-12",
    "value": 70.32183347555772
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-03-05",
    "value": 73.36286201022146
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-03-26",
    "value": 74.79360018220122
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-04-02",
    "value": 79.07588060050237
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-04-09",
    "value": 72.68569443640364
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-04-23",
    "value": 78.49819059107358
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-05-21",
    "value": 74.21070693205216
  },
  {
    "date": "2017-05-28",
    "value": 76.16108625212159
  }
]
**/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj = '{ "2017-05-28": "76.16108625212159", "2017-02-12": "70.32183347555772", "2017-05-21": "74.21070693205216", "2017-04-23": "78.49819059107358", "2017-03-05": "73.36286201022146", "2017-04-02": "79.07588060050237", "2017-01-29": "79.07021235890568", "2017-03-26": "74.79360018220122", "2017-01-22": "71.80166785183269", "2017-04-09": "72.68569443640364" }';
pobject = JSON.parse(obj);
arr = Object.keys(pobject);
sorted = arr.sort();
len = sorted.length;
for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
val= pobject[sorted[i]];
console.log(val);
}
```

This will work

Hope this helps..!

Comment: @john_js_py , this is done by using js native functions for sorting

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

You can not order object proprieties. so you may need to convert your object to an array

**Example**

```js
var obj = {
        "2017-05-28": 76.16108625212159,
        "2017-02-12": 70.32183347555772,
        "2017-05-21": 74.21070693205216,
        "2017-04-23": 78.49819059107358,
        "2017-03-05": 73.36286201022146,
        "2017-04-02": 79.07588060050237,
        "2017-01-29": 79.07021235890568,
        "2017-03-26": 74.79360018220122,
        "2017-01-22": 71.80166785183269,
        "2017-04-09": 72.68569443640364
    },

    sortedArr = Object.keys(obj)
        .sort(function (a, b) { 
            return new Date(a) - new Date(b)
         })
        .reduce(function (acc, item, index) {
            acc.push({
                date: item,
                value: obj[item]
            });
            return acc;
        }, []);
    console.log(sortedArr);
```

*Thanks @Shivam for your note*

Comment: Though this would give out the object with keys ordered, But that is not guaranteed, More about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Comment: @Shivam Thank you very much, Updated!